# Inhomogeneous Wave Equation in 3 dimensions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

From section 7.5 in [this source](http://www.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf), I see that, for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u\left(\vec{x},t\right)}{\partial t^2} 
   - \nabla^2u\left(\vec{x},t\right)
   =f\left(\vec{x},t\right),\qquad
u\left(\vec{x},0\right) = \phi\left(\vec{x}\right), \qquad
\left.\frac{\partial u\left(\vec{x},0\right)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} = \psi\left(\vec{x}\right)
$$
... then ...
$$
u\left(\vec{x},t\right) = 
  \frac{1}{4\pi t^2} 
     \oint_{\partial B \left(\vec{x},t\right)}
       \left[
         \phi\left(\vec{y}\right) + t\psi\left(\vec{y}\right) + \nabla \phi\left(\vec{y}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{y}-\vec{x}\right)
       \right]\;dS\left(\vec{y}\right)
+ \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{4\pi\left(t-s\right)} \left[
    \oint_{\partial B\left(\vec{x},t-s\right)} f\left(\vec{y},s\right)\; dS\left(\vec{y}\right)\right]\;ds
$$
I have two questions.

My **First Question** is, if I have:
$$
\color{blue}{
\color{red}{\frac{1}{c^2}}\frac{\partial^2 u\left(\vec{x},t\right)}{\partial t^2} 
   - \nabla^2u\left(\vec{x},t\right)
   =f\left(\vec{x},t\right),\qquad
u\left(\vec{x},0\right) = \phi\left(\vec{x}\right), \qquad
\left.\frac{\partial u\left(\vec{x},0\right)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} = \psi\left(\vec{x}\right)
}
$$
...is it true that  ...
$$
\large{
\color{blue}{
u\left(\vec{x},t\right) = 
  \frac{1}{4\pi \color{red}{c^2}t^2} 
     \oint_{\partial B \left(\vec{x},\color{red}{c}t\right)}
       \left[
         \phi\left(\vec{y}\right) + t\psi\left(\vec{y}\right) + \nabla \phi\left(\vec{y}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{y}-\vec{x}\right)
       \right]\;dS\left(\vec{y}\right)
+ \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{4\pi\left(t-s\right)} \left[
    \oint_{\partial B\left(\vec{x},\color{red}{c}t-\color{red}{c}s\right)} f\left(\vec{y},s\right)\; dS\left(\vec{y}\right)\right]\;ds
}
}
$$
(I have highlighted in red the difference from the earlier expression)

For $c \neq 1$, the first term is worked out in section 7.2 of the same source which details the case where $f\left(\vec{x},t\right)\equiv0$ (Kirchhoff's Formula). I have tried to apply a change of variables the same way on the second term, but I'm looking for some confirmation (or correction!) that in this term $\partial B\left(\vec{x}, \color{red}{c}t - \color{red}{c}s\right)$ is the only place where $c$ will appear.

My **Second Question** is, is the expression above actually identical to the following (focus on the second term)?
$$
\large{
\color{blue}{
u\left(\vec{x},t\right) = 
  \frac{1}{4\pi} 
     \left[\oint_{\partial B \left(\vec{x},{c}t\right)}
       \frac{
         \phi\left(\vec{y}\right) + t\psi\left(\vec{y}\right) + \nabla \phi\left(\vec{y}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{y}-\vec{x}\right)
       }{c^2t^2}\;dS\left(\vec{y}\right)\right]
+ \frac {1}{4\pi} \left[
    \iiint_{B\left(\vec{x},ct\right)} 
        \frac{f\left(\vec{y},t-\dfrac{\left|\vec{y}-\vec{x}\right|}{c}\right)}{\left|\vec{y}-\vec{x}\right|}
    \; dV\left(\vec{y}\right)
  \right]
}
}
$$

Thanks...